# MWE from sa-tikz documentation gives error in latest TeXlive distrubtion

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been having trouble with this example from the `sa-tikz` documentation (taken from page 21 [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/sa-tikz/doc/sa-tikz-doc.pdf))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sa-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[N=8,r1=4,M=8,r3=4,clos rear={module label opacity=0}] {};
\draw[red,ultra thick](r1-2-input-1)–(r1-2-output-2)
(r2-2-input-2)–(r2-2-output-3)
(r3-3-input-2)–(r3-3-output-2);
\draw[red,ultra thick](r1-4-input-1)–(r1-4-output-1)
(r2-1-input-4)–(r2-1-output-1)
(r3-1-input-1)–(r3-1-output-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems to present an error of

```
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
```

on each of the `\draw` commands (lines 8 and 11). Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think something has gone wrong in the making of that manual, if you look carefully at your code, you have en dashes (`–`) between coordinates. It should be a pair of hyphens (`--`), as usual with TikZ.

The error message does hint that the problem lies there, at least for me:

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \draw[red,ultra thick](r1-2-input-1)�
                                          ��(r1-2-output-2)
```

Note the funny characters between the two coordinates.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sa-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[N=8,r1=4,M=8,r3=4,clos rear={module label opacity=0}] {};
\draw[red,ultra thick](r1-2-input-1)--(r1-2-output-2)
(r2-2-input-2)--(r2-2-output-3)
(r3-3-input-2)--(r3-3-output-2);
\draw[red,ultra thick](r1-4-input-1)--(r1-4-output-1)
(r2-1-input-4)--(r2-1-output-1)
(r3-1-input-1)--(r3-1-output-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've notified [Claudio Fiandrino](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino), the package author, about this, so it will be fixed at some point.